# How do I show the function $I:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $I(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{e^{x}-e^{t}}}$ has a unique maximum?

Tags: calculus, analysis, matlab, leibniz-integral-rule

I've seen that $I$ satisfies that $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}I(x)=0$$and also that$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}I(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x}}}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{e^{t}}{e^{x}}}}=0,$$ so by Rolle's theorem there must be at least one maximum in $(0,+\infty)$. And I have to prove that there is only one maximum, I just don't seem to be able to do it because when I use Leibniz's integral rule I get that $$I'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x}-e^{x}}}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{x}}{2\sqrt{\left(e^{x}-e^{t}\right)^{3}}}dt$$ which explodes because of the first term. I don't know how to get further than this step.

Although it's better to have a mathematical proof, it would also be helpful to be able to plot the function on MatLab, it just keeps giving me dimension errors somehow. All help will be welcome.

Comment: **Hint:** Compute $I''(x)$ and check its sign.

Comment: The function is actually differentiable anyway, even though the Leibniz rule fails. You can try writing $\int_0^{x+h} (e^{x+h}-e^t)^{-1/2} dt - \int_0^x (e^x-e^t)^{-1/2} dt = \int_x^{x+h} (e^{x+h}-e^t)^{-1/2} dt$ $+ \int_0^x (e^{x+h}-e^t)^{-1/2} - (e^x-e^t)^{-1/2} dt$ and expand inside the integrals to get the coefficient you need. Not sure how easily it will work, though, because I'm not so sure how to correctly handle the $-1/2$ power in there.

Comment: Thanks! This actually gave me the idea of developing the inside term of the integral $\int_{0}^{x}\left(e^{x}-e^{t}\right)^{-1/2}dt$ as a power series, and after some tricks, a first order ODE and some Dominated Convergence Theorem, I managed to prove the result. This was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{e^{x}-e^{t}}}=\int \frac{dt}{e^{x/2}\sqrt{1-e^{(t-x)}}}$$
$$t=x+\log(u) \implies dt=\frac {du}u\implies I=e^{x/2}\int\frac {du}{u \sqrt{1-u} }$$
$$u=1-v^2 \implies \int\frac {du}{u \sqrt{1-u} }=2\int \frac {dv}{1-v^2}=-2 \tanh ^{-1}(v) $$

Back to $x$ and using the bounds leads to
$$J(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{e^{x}-e^{t}}}=2 e^{-x/2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-x/2} \sqrt{e^x-1}\right)$$
$$J'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}-e^{-x/2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-x/2} \sqrt{e^x-1}\right)$$

By inspection or graphing, the solution is just above $x=1$ and Newton methods gives the folloxing iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000 \\
 1 & 1.1597496 \\
 2 & 1.1862399 \\
 3 & 1.1868419 \\
 4 & 1.1868422
\end{array}
\right)$$
and, at this point, $J''(x)=-0.47692$ confirms that this is a maximum.